# Regular fonts for git-gui and gitk have disappeared

Tags: git-gui, gitk

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.
Recently, the fonts in my git-gui and gitk have suddenly changed.
I have tried the other fonts proposed but none of them correspond to the previous one that I was used to.

This is what it looked before the bug (taken from the web) :

[image]
[image]

This is what it looks like now :

[image]
[image]

The current fonts for git gui are :

- Main : gothic 11pt
- diff/console : gothic 11pt

The current fonts for gitk are :

- Main : courrier 10 pitch
- diff : monospace
- user interface : gothic

The fonts I can choose from are :

bitstream charter, clean, clearlyu alternate glyphs, clearlyu arabic, clearlyu arabic extra, clearlyu devanagari, clearlyu devangari extra, clearlyu pua, courrier 10 pitch, fangsong ti, fixed, gothic, mincho, newspaper, nil, open look cursor, open look glyph, song ti

Can someone check what is the normal default font for git-gui and gitk on Ubuntu 16.04, and maybe explain why they have changed in my case ? Maybe I incidentally removed a package...

I tried to reinstall gitk and git gui, but I still get that font... The difference is that at the beginning, the default fonts in gitk are Helvetica, Courier and Helvetica, and when I click on the button to choose the font, they don't appear in the list.
Could that be a Tcl/Tk problem ?

Comment: A very similar issue was described when`Tcl/Tk` is upgraded but unfortunately this wasn't solved till now: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127709/how-to-disable-anti-aliasing-in-git-gui-and-gitk/127710

Comment: Hi Sergey ! Thank you for directing me to this ! Can you make an answer with the same link, so that I can at least give you the bounty instead of it just being lost ?

Comment: Hi, Matthieu, so you've solved the problem? Nice to know that. I moved comment content to the answer

Comment: I haven't tried the solution in your link, but it's already a solution, even if it seems hard to do, so it's better than nothing :)
When you say "this wasn't solved till now", you mean "this hasn't been solved yet" right ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I finally figured out where this is coming from, and it's because of the Anaconda environment.

`git-gui` and `gitk` use `Tcl/Tk` and `tkinter` as a GUI library, and as mentionned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47787749/4195725):

> `tkinter` works linking to a Tk/Tcl interpreter that, loosely
>   speaking, is contained in a couple of DLL, in particular the graphical
>   library is `libtk6.0.so`.
>
> Most of the extra fonts not seen by `tkinter` are managed by the
>   Freetype library and Anaconda's libtk6.0.so is not built against
>   Freetype...

I have made the test, and I can conclude that it is very well coming from this :

```
$ conda deactivate
$ gitk                 # fonts are okay
$ conda activate base
$ (base) gitk          # fonts are weird
$ (base) conda deactivate
$ gitk                 # fonts are okay again
```

One workaround is the one mentionned [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6833#issuecomment-387752000):

> I resolved this issue by removing `wish` files in ANACONDA_PATH/bin and
>   related virtual environments

Except that I *renamed* the files instead of removing them, e.g. `wish` -> `wish-i-renamed-it`.

Sources :

[Make Anaconda's tkinter aware of system fonts or install new fonts for Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769187/make-anacondas-tkinter-aware-of-system-fonts-or-install-new-fonts-for-anaconda)

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6833

---

**This old answer doesn't apply anymore**

I just restarted my computer this morning, and the fonts are back !
They are all here !
I really don't know why though...

Here is my update log :

```
$ less /var/log/apt/history.log

Start-Date: 2018-06-05  09:36:17
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.127'
Upgrade: liblouis9:amd64 (2.6.4-2ubuntu0.1, 2.6.4-2ubuntu0.2), snapd:amd64 (2.32.3.2, 2.32.9), python3-louis:amd64 (2.6.4-2ubuntu0.1, 2.6.4-2ubuntu0.2), libexempi3:amd64 (2.2.2-2, 2.2.2-2ubuntu0.1), liblouis-data:amd64 (2.6.4-2ubuntu0.1, 2.6.4-2ubuntu0.2)
End-Date: 2018-06-05  09:36:36

Start-Date: 2018-06-06  08:31:53
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.100'
Upgrade: libelf1:amd64 (0.165-3ubuntu1, 0.165-3ubuntu1.1), libelf1:i386 (0.165-3ubuntu1, 0.165-3ubuntu1.1)
End-Date: 2018-06-06  08:31:57

Start-Date: 2018-06-06  08:32:51
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.100'
Upgrade: git-gui:amd64 (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.3, 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.4), git-man:amd64 (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.3, 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.4), git:amd64 (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.3, 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.4), gitk:amd64 (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.3, 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.4)
End-Date: 2018-06-06  08:33:03

Start-Date: 2018-06-07  10:39:47
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.124'
Upgrade: liblouis9:amd64 (2.6.4-2ubuntu0.2, 2.6.4-2ubuntu0.3), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (67.0.3396.62-1, 67.0.3396.79-1), python3-louis:amd64 (2.6.4-2ubuntu0.2, 2.6.4-2ubuntu0.3), liblouis-data:amd64 (2.6.4-2ubuntu0.2, 2.6.4-2ubuntu0.3)
End-Date: 2018-06-07  10:40:04

Start-Date: 2018-06-13  08:46:19
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.107'
Install: linux-headers-4.4.0-128:amd64 (4.4.0-128.154, automatic), linux-headers-4.4.0-128-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-128.154, automatic), linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-128.154, automatic), linux-signed-image-4.4.0-128-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-128.154, automatic), linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-128.154, automatic)
Upgrade: libimage-magick-perl:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11), linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.127.133, 4.4.0.128.134), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-127.153, 4.4.0-128.154), libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.2, 2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.3), libldap-2.4-2:i386 (2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.2, 2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.3), libimage-magick-q16-perl:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11), imagemagick:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11), adobe-flash-properties-gtk:amd64 (1:20180508.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1:20180607.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), linux-image-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.127.133, 4.4.0.128.134), libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11), linux-signed-image-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.127.133, 4.4.0.128.134), slack-desktop:amd64 (3.2.0-beta25a7a50e, 3.2.1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (67.0.3396.79-1, 67.0.3396.87-1), linux-signed-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.127.133, 4.4.0.128.134), adobe-flashplugin:amd64 (1:20180508.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1:20180607.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), imagemagick-6.q16:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11), libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11), firefox-locale-en:amd64 (60.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 60.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), firefox-locale-fr:amd64 (60.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 60.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), gpgv:amd64 (1.4.20-1ubuntu3.1, 1.4.20-1ubuntu3.2), libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11), firefox:amd64 (60.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 60.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), imagemagick-common:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11), libmagick++-6.q16-5v5:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11), gnupg:amd64 (1.4.20-1ubuntu3.1, 1.4.20-1ubuntu3.2), linux-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.127.133, 4.4.0.128.134), spotify-client:amd64 (1:1.0.77.338.g758ebd78-41, 1:1.0.80.480.g51b03ac3-13)
End-Date: 2018-06-13  08:49:26

Start-Date: 2018-06-14  15:36:26
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.128'
Upgrade: perl-base:amd64 (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.3, 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5), perl-modules-5.22:amd64 (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.3, 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5), console-setup-linux:amd64 (1.108ubuntu15.3, 1.108ubuntu15.4), console-setup:amd64 (1.108ubuntu15.3, 1.108ubuntu15.4), libperl5.22:amd64 (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.3, 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5), keyboard-configuration:amd64 (1.108ubuntu15.3, 1.108ubuntu15.4), perl:amd64 (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.3, 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5)
End-Date: 2018-06-14  15:37:04

Start-Date: 2018-06-15  10:36:50
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.152'
Upgrade: gnupg-agent:amd64 (2.1.11-6ubuntu2, 2.1.11-6ubuntu2.1), ruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04.9, 2.3.1-2~16.04.10), libmagic1:amd64 (1:5.25-2ubuntu1, 1:5.25-2ubuntu1.1), ruby2.3-dev:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04.9, 2.3.1-2~16.04.10), dirmngr:amd64 (2.1.11-6ubuntu2, 2.1.11-6ubuntu2.1), libruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04.9, 2.3.1-2~16.04.10), gnupg2:amd64 (2.1.11-6ubuntu2, 2.1.11-6ubuntu2.1), file:amd64 (1:5.25-2ubuntu1, 1:5.25-2ubuntu1.1)
End-Date: 2018-06-15  10:37:08

Start-Date: 2018-06-19  09:04:17
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.168'
Upgrade: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.20.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.20.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.20.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.20.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), desktop-file-utils:amd64 (0.22-1ubuntu5.1, 0.22-1ubuntu5.2), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.20.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.20.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), wireless-regdb:amd64 (2015.07.20-1ubuntu1, 2018.05.09-0ubuntu1~16.04.1), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64 (2.20.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.20.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.20.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.20.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
End-Date: 2018-06-19  09:04:32

Start-Date: 2018-06-20  10:39:10
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.182'
Upgrade: libgcrypt20:amd64 (1.6.5-2ubuntu0.4, 1.6.5-2ubuntu0.5), libgcrypt20:i386 (1.6.5-2ubuntu0.4, 1.6.5-2ubuntu0.5)
End-Date: 2018-06-20  10:39:15

Start-Date: 2018-06-21  16:30:24
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.214'
Upgrade: amd64-microcode:amd64 (2.20160316.1, 3.20180524.1~ubuntu0.16.04.1)
End-Date: 2018-06-21  16:30:48
```

And this is my reboot log :

```
$ last -x | grep reboot

reboot   system boot  4.4.0-128-generi Tue Jun 26 09:08   still running
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-128-generi Fri Jun 15 10:38 - 18:33 (10+07:55)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-127-generi Tue Jun 12 09:26 - 18:33 (13+09:06)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-127-generi Tue Jun 12 09:21 - 09:25  (00:03)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-127-generi Tue Jun  5 16:43 - 09:20 (6+16:37)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-127-generi Mon Jun  4 12:54 - 09:20 (7+20:26)
```

The only way I could see why is the fact that I upgraded git-gui and gitk on June 6th.
But why did only work when rebooting on the 26th ?
There is no Tcl/Tk upgrade, but there are gtk upgrades, so I don't know if that has something to do with it...
Maybe someone can figure it out ?

Comment: Slightly off-topic (since the OP used Ubuntu): If you have the same problem on Gentoo, the root cause is the same - lacking truetype support in tk (libtk8.6.so isn't linked to the FreeType library). The solution is straight forward - enable the `truetype` USE flag for the `dev-lang/tk` package.

Comment: Thank you! :) I also fell for this conda env trap!

Comment: Great find - there is since 2023 [a fix](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6833#issuecomment-387752000), I've added my answer  with the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as [@matthieu says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51037685/327074) its an anaconda problem.

Right at the end of the [GitHub issue #6833](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6833) is [this comment](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6833#issuecomment-387752000) which has merged a fix.

Now you should be able to do:

```bash
sudo apt install -y libxft2
conda install -c conda-forge tk=*=xft_*
```

This immediately brought all my fonts back. Didn't need to restart the terminal.