# How to display Russian language in Tkinter text widget? (Currently only seeing unicode)

Tags: linux, tkinter, unicode, fonts, tkinter-text

Does anybody know what my problem is?
I'm starting some work on tkinter and when I copy/paste a bit of Russian Text to my tkinter text widget it looks like this

[image: rus unicode]

Here is the original text

> Лиса вышла холодной ночью.
> Он молился, чтобы луна дала ему свет.
> Ибо в ту ночь ему предстояло пройти много миль.

Can someone help me correctly display this text on tkinter?

some information.

- I am using a conda environment
- python 3.7
- OS is CentOS

Steps to reproduce my environment.

1. setup a conda environment (my python version is 3.7)
   https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html
2. set conda environment as interpreter in pycharm
3. code

> ```
> import tkinter as tk
>
> window = tk.Tk()
> txt_align = tk.Text(master=window)
> txt_align.grid(sticky="nsew", padx=5, pady=5)
>
> window.mainloop()
> ```

if you want you can also do

```
text = "Лиса вышла холодной ночью. Он молился, чтобы луна дала ему свет. Ибо в ту ночь ему предстояло пройти много миль."
txt_align.insert(tk.END, text)
print(text)
```

but my results stay the same unfortunately.

4. copy russian text
   Лиса вышла холодной ночью.
   Он молился, чтобы луна дала ему свет.
   Ибо в ту ночь ему предстояло пройти много миль.
5. paste it into tkinter text box

things I've tried:

- I tried importing codecs and opening my text file containing the Russian text that way with encoding = utf-8

More info:
When I 'get' the text from the text widget and print to console, it displays Russian just fine.
-English,French works just fine but Korean, Chinese, arabic all display in this weird format

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Comment: updated post with steps to mimic my env @JosefZ

Comment: Found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170918/tkinter-font-not-changing-on-python-3-6-8-ubuntu-18-04lts conda's python seems to be janky