# Tkinter shows only the basic 'fixed' font is available. How to load other fonts to Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am asking tkinter to tell me the different fonts available with

```
import tkinter.font as font
print(font.families())
```

It returns ('fixed',) meaning that apparently only a single, default font is available. So when I try to set the font type, size or weight of e.g. a Text widget this has no effect.

However, in my CENTOS installation there are a few fonts installed, e.g. the liberation font I would like to use under /usr/share/fonts/liberation .

How can I make this font available to tkinter? Apparently it doesn't find the fonts under /usr/share/fonts/.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference: I didn't progress at all in this matter. There is a similar topic here

[Make Anaconda's tkinter aware of system fonts or install new fonts for Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769187/make-anacondas-tkinter-aware-of-system-fonts-or-install-new-fonts-for-anaconda/73077180#73077180)

however I was unable to make xfontsel work as it is described there.