# Changing tkinter default font in a conda environment

Tags: python, tkinter, miniconda

I am running a small test program

**font.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

root = tk.Tk()

font_size = 24
fonts = [
    'Arial',
    'Droid sans Mono',
    'Fira Code',
    'TSCu_comic',
    'Inconsolata',
    ]

for font in fonts:
    my_font = tkFont.Font(family=font, size=font_size)
    root.option_add('*Font', my_font)
    label = tk.Label(root, text='Hello, world!')
    label.pack()
    
root.mainloop()
```

If I run it outside a conda environment it works

[image]

In the environment some fonts do not change and others are rendered anomalously

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Also, by conda environment, do you mean Anaconda?

Comment: No errors. Miniconda

Comment: Does it happen for system fonts, extra fonts or all types of fonts?

Comment: I've updated the question. As you can see it works for some fonts, not others

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter uses some dynamic link libraries(DLLs) for displaying UI elements. For graphics, Tkinter uses the `libtk6.0.so`. Most extra fonts that are display anomalously are maintained by a library called `Freetype`. The `libtk6.0.so` of Miniconda(or Anaconda) does not work with `Freetype`. So, extra fonts are either displayed anomalously or experience a loss in quality. One method is to substitute the DLL. This is not good practice, but serves your purpose. To do it, you can use the following code:

```
$ mv lib/miniconda3/lib/libtk8.6.so lib/miniconda3/lib/libtk8.6.sav
$ ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtk8.6.so lib/miniconda3/lib/libtk8.6.so
$ ipython
Python 3.8.2 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov 11 2023, 23:42:23) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
In [1]: from tkinter import Tk, Label ; from tkinter.font import families
In [2]: r = Tk() ; a = families() ; len(a)
Out[2]: 328
In [3]: r=Tk() ;  Label(r, text="Constantia", font=("Constantia", 60)).pack()
In [4]: r.mainloop()
```

You can have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769187/make-anacondas-tkinter-aware-of-system-fonts-or-install-new-fonts-for-anaconda) for more info.

Comment: My app will be distributed as a ZippApp and I'm only using conda an as environment for development - guess it's back to pyenv for tkinter apps